# Segregating user data with AWS Amplify

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm following the AWS Amplify tutorials on [API](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/ios) and [Authentication](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/ios). While I've made progress to get both working (!), it's not clear to me how I might connect the two features of Amplify so as to separate/segregate (?) user data...

For instance, take this GraphQL Todo Model:

```
type Todo @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  completed: Boolean!
}
```

I can save and fetch these `Todo`s with a ViewModel:

```swift
import Amplify

class TodoListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var todos = [Todo]()
    @Published var completedTodos = [Todo]()
    
    func loadToDos() {
        Amplify.DataStore.query(Todo.self) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let todos):
                self.todos = todos.filter { !$0.completed }
                self.completedTodos = todos.filter { $0.completed }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Could not query DataStore: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func createTodo(name: String, description: String?) {
        let item = Todo(name: name, description: description, completed: false)
        todos.append(item)
        Amplify.DataStore.save(item) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let savedItem):
                print("Saved item: \(savedItem.name)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Could not save item with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But these methods seemingly allow *any* user to access *any* other users Todo data (?)

Reading through the docs, I think I need to setup [authorization rules](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/setup-auth-rules/q/platform/ios) (?)

If I'm reading this correctly, to make sure that an *arbitrary* user can only see *their* data, is it really as simple as changing the GraphQL Todo model to:

```
type Todo @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  completed: Boolean!
}
```

That can't be it?

...what other modifications will I need to implement in order to ensure that "Alice" can save and fetch her data and be sure that I'm not mixing it with "Bob's" data?

A fully worked example that uses an Authenticated (logged-in) user would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It really is that simple. That's the value of using Amplify. Every record that is saved to the database has a column called `owner`. The value of `owner` is the Id of the Cognito user that created the record.

AppSync's auto-generated resolvers are smart enough to verify that the user asking for data is the same user that owns the data.